# Changing version of cxf on Service Mix

Tags: cxf, updates, apache-servicemix

I want to change the version of cxf on Service Mix 7.0.1 where cxf version is 3.1.9 . Because of using Brave tracing that is implemented in 3.1.12 version of cxf.

So Is there a way to change the version of the CXF on Service Mix.

I have deleted manually everything in the system/apache/cxf folder that has 3.1.9 version and add a file with 3.2.5 version. But it is still not working. When I write feature:list all of the cxf dependencies are with 3.1.9 version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting files from the system folder won't work. It does not scan the system folder for files, but rather uses it as a cache to go looking for specific versions. You don't need to add new versions to system either because it will download them from the central maven repo it they arn't in system.

If it starts up without a data folder, it will install features & versions listed in org.apache.karaf.features.cfg
One would expect to be able to delete the data folder, change the version in org.apache.karaf.features.cfg & start it up, but I tried that and Camel was broken.  Unsure why.

I find it easier to deal with it using the management console.
Install the management console by dropping the following xml file into the deploy folder:

```
<features name="features-murray" xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0 http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.0">
    <repository>mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.5.7/xml/features</repository>
    <feature name="murray" version="1" install="auto">
        <feature>hawtio-offline</feature>
    </feature>
</features>
```

Then point your browser at http://localhost:8181/hawtio and login with SMX/SMX.
From OSGI/Features add the your new feature version with the plus button: 
mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.1.12/xml/features
It may take some time to install, because it downloads it from the net.  I found it bounced me out of the management console also, but after logging back in I could uninstall the old cxf 3.1.9.  It again logged me out of the management console, but after logging back in I had Camel active and CXF on 3.1.12.
No testing though - goodness knows what else is broken.

Comment: It is working. Thank you a lot! Btw is it possible to use two versions of cxf? For example i will use the default one for some stuff and 3.2.5 for brave?